# One of the columns in my dataframe is a date column, how can I add a new column to the dataframe being the difference of today vs that date in days?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a bunch of dates in the following format

```
LastUpdated
2021-06-19 12:41:38
2021-06-20 15:09:05
2021-06-20 15:09:39
2021-06-28 08:59:29
2021-08-03 14:02:03
```

Last updated being the name of that column in my dataframe. How can I add an extra column to the dataframe which will be the difference in days between now and the date of each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope your `LastUpdated` column is already of type `datetime64`. If not, convert it using `pd.to_datetime`. That makes datetime calculation a lot easier. The trick to get the difference in days, hours, minutes, etc. is to divide the Timedelta object with `pd.Timedelta(<unit>=1)`:

```py
df["LastUpdated"] = pd.to_datetime(df["LastUpdated"])
df["Diff"] = (pd.Timestamp.now() - df["LastUpdated"]) / pd.Timedelta(days=1)

# If you want to strip out the time
df["Diff"] = (pd.Timestamp.now().normalize() - df["LastUpdated"].dt.normalize()) / pd.Timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Since you mention it, is there a function i can call to check the type of a column in my dataframe?

Comment: Use `df.dtypes`

Comment: Thanks. It says that the LastUpdated column is "object". Not sure how helpful is that. I also tried your code above, I'm getting 
```TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Timestamp' and 'str'

Comment: `object` means the column is a generic placeholder for non-pandas-specialized data types. Most often, it means the column is stored string. But it can also be list, dict, etc. In this case, we want to specialize the data type to `datetime64`. See my edited answer